# How can I access the hapi plugin name?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am working on node using **hapi** framework. New to this so I apologize if it comes out to be very basic.

I want to access a plugin name within the plugin files. 
Use case is I want to access the plugin options from the server object. 
So I can do `server.registrations[plugin_name].options`.

My workflow at that point (where I require the options) is not inside the register method ( *I run an independent script that just needs to initialize the server, not start it; so no routes here*) so not able to access the options from there, but I have the `server` object available.

Also, what is the correct way to expose the plugin options to other **files** within the plugin? If I need the options after a lot of nesting of files etc , it is very chaotic to keep passing the options object somehow from file to file, method to method.

Not really clear how to work this problem out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a 100% sure what your question is but if you expose your options in a script (module) that can be required by both your plugin and any other files that you want to use the same options object that will allow you to access the same object in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if i understood correct, you can do like this.

```
const Plugins = require('./Plugins');

//Register All Plugins
server.register(Plugins, err => {
    if (err){
        server.error(`Error while loading plugins : ${err}`)
    }else {
        server.log('info', 'Plugins Loaded')
    }
});
```

Comment: No sorry, I know how to register them, I'm asking about the options  - passed to a plugin during registration - how to make them available to other files within the plugin.